# How to fully purge KMail settings in KDE5

Tags: kde5, kmail

Due to some misconfigurations I want to completely purge my KMail to behave like a brand new one. When I follow the steps in https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/pim/kmail2/clean-start-after-a-failed-migration.html all my mail accounts are gone when I start KMail anew. However, if I go to the "configure KMail" settings dialog to the mail accounts view, my mailing identities and the account information for sending emails are still there. In addition, after one of the first tries an "unknown" identity showed up and with every time I remove the respective files according to the howto in the link above, this "unknown" identiy is doubled.

So obviously, the steps from the kde link are not sufficient to really purge all the information about my mail configuration.

Can anyone tell me, where the remaining information is stored and can be removed?

Answer (score 1):

I used

```
grep -r <email-address-part> ~/.config
```

and that showed that it's necessary to remove the following files:

```
rm .config/email* .config/mailtransports
```

Comment: Did you try whether this does really solves the issue described in the question or did you just assume that it should be somehow related?

Comment: Yes, it really solved exactly the same issue for me. Of course I deleted all the other data related to Akonadi and KMail.